# Using regex to insert a space in a string in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a string that is not properly formed and am attempting to correct it. An example of the string is: -

*A Someone(US)B Nobody(US)*

I am attempting to correct it to: -

**A Someone(US) B Nobody(US)**

I am using the below code to match ")" followed by a capital letter and using php's preg_replace function to do the match and add the space. However I'm completely rubbish at regex and cannot get the space added in the correct place.

```
$regex = "([\)][A-Z])";
$replacement = ") $0";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $output);
```

Can anyone suggest a better method? I realise the space is not adding correclty because $0 contains the data I am matching, is there a way to manipulate $0?

Comment: $0 is capture group zero which is `([\)][A-Z])`, just move the paranthesis like this `[\)]([A-Z])` and use $1 I think.

Comment: I don't think there is a capture group $1, I've tried this and it chops off the capital letter, so produces an output of A Someone(US)  Nobody(US).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\))(?=\p{Lu})/u', ' ', $output);
```

inserts a space between a closing parenthesis (`\)`) and an uppercase letter (`\p{Lu}`). You don't need `$0` (or `$1` etc.) at all since you're just inserting something at a position between two characters, and this regex matches exactly this (zero-width) position. Check out [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: How would you adapt this to lowercase letter preceding a capital letter again no space? I tried /(?<=\))(?=\p{Lu})/u but no joy..

Comment: Do you mean "insert a space between a lowercase and an uppercase letter"? `$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})/u', ' ', $output);`

Answer (score 0):

how about regex=`"(?<=\))[A-Z]"`
and replacement=`" $0"`

Comment: This regex causes an Unknown modifier '[' error when used with preg_replace.